# Why am I required to alloc/init instances of an class before assigning values to the objects properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instantiation, allocation

Dumbed down example pertaining to what I am wondering...
So I have a custom class and I declare an instance of the class.

**MyCustomClass *objectA;**

**objectA.property = value;**

IF I NSLog(@"print the value: %@", objectA.property);

it will return nil.

NOW IF I declared it as such...
MyCustomClass *objectA = [MyCustomClass alloc] init];

and then assign it's value...

**objectA.property = value;**

Everything is all happy-go-lucky...

Ultimately, I wonder why X-Code wouldn't automatically instantiate the object in memory when it sees that I am assigning it's properties in the code.  From a Developer's point of view is it better that it doesn't do it for me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. It's all about how Objective-C works at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Tom's answer covers why the runtime **can't** safely create an initialize an object for you.

The next point is this: Objective-C does not do anything for you "because it could tell that it should." There is no automatic magic. If you want an object, you create an initialize an object. If you don't, the pointer is nil.

Compilers are getting smarter, it's true, but that sort of "you must have meant to create an object, so I'll just silently do it for you" behavior would mean that you, the programmer, can't tell for sure what's going on.

Some 4th generation (interpreted) languages do setup like this for you, but I can't think of any compiled/3rd generation languages that do.

Comment: And there's the other good point that I started to think up as well... If the compiler began making "assumptions" we would find far too many "cracks in the code" because we simply thought the compiler would take care of it for me.  It's those hard rules sometimes that let us debug much quicker because the rules to play by are hardened sometimes.  Although there always seems to be exceptions to every rule but I think in my junior level here, just knowing the rules is more important than how to break them and still have a working code.

Thanks for taking the time, Duncan!

-Wade

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why X-Code wouldn't automatically instantiate the object in memory when it sees that I am assigning it's properties in the code.

Because, what is the right way to instantiate `MyCustomClass`? Often it's enough to `alloc` and `init` an instance, as in your sample code. But in many cases this would result in broken, nonfunctioning objects due to not calling the designated initializer. For example, if `MyCustomClass` were a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, just calling `init` would get you a useless object.

In Swift, classes can differentiate between designated and convenience initializers, but this still doesn't make it safe to auto-instantiate objects as you describe. Designated initializers usually exist because you must provide one or more arguments to the initializer for it to work properly. For example, what if the object were an `NSString`? You can call `alloc` and `init` to get one, but doing so is almost always wrong. What arguments should be used when automatically instantiating an object? Neither Xcode nor Clang can really know, and neither can the Objective-C run time.

Comment: You make a great point there.... Just like you may really want to do something like...

NSArray *array = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:<#(id), ...#>, nil];  

That's a good explanation.  Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of good answers already. Here's another angle.

When you write:

```
MyCustomClass *objectA;
```

What you're saying to the compiler is that `objectA` is a name for a location in memory---an address---where you expect to store an object of class `MyCustomClass`. You haven't actually created such an object yet.

You could put a `MyCustomClass` instance at that address by creating a new one with `alloc`/`init`. But at this point you don't have to, and the compiler can't assume you will. You could just as well get one from elsewhere—calling some other method on some other class that returns a `MyCustomClass`, or pulling one out of an array, etc.

Because you don't yet have an object—only a place for one—attempting to set a property on it has no effect. So, when you call

```
objectA.property = value;
```

At this time, `objectA` is nil—nothing, an empty address. One of the rules of ObjC is that when you try to do something to nothing, nothing happens and you get nothing back. (This feature can be useful at times and frustrating at others.) So this line is a no-op.

Comment: This is a better answer, because it doesn't presuppose that OP understands the difference between declaring a pointer type for an object vs allocating memory for an object. (I think that's the source of confusion for him/her.)

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much.  Yes exactly! When you try to do something to nothing, nothing happens and you get back nothing.  It certainly can be frustrating sometimes.  My teacher here at Mobile Makers gave me a good rule to follow for now as I push forward.  First, I will instantiate my object locally and alloc/init within the method as I need them so that I can see everything happening together.   Thanks for taking the time to answer.  "He" is very appreciative of this! lol.